# Use environment variable in .htaccess to deal with two RewriteBase statements

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Imagine a WordPress installation with two versions, in one of them, the URLs start with **example.com/shop** and the other **example.com/nl/shop**

Using the following htaccess file, I constantly need to uncomment two lines and comment out two others to switch between two versions of the site.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  #RewriteBase /shop/
  RewriteBase /nl/shop/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
  RewriteRule . /nl/shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As a potential fix, I used the following htaccess file which take advantages of an environment variable named BASE:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It works for both versions, however now I can't access the admin area which
has the **~/shop/wp-admin/** or **~/nl/shop/wp-admin/** in its URI, because of too many redirect error.

What should I change to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the given solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36086105/4939050), I made a small change to my RewriteRule directive and now the redirect error is gone for good.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code -

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^mysite1/(.*)$ mysite1/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^mysite2/(.*)$ mysite2/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution doesn't work for example.com/shop/something or example.com/nl/shop/something